# No Google icon after installing the google-plugin-eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

After I installed google plugin for eclipse 4.4, the blue Google icon does not appear in the toolbar. And when I check in the installation details of Eclipse, the plugin is listed as installed, but in Preference there isn't any "Google" entry.

The problem is, I have tried the solution suggested in the plugin's FAQ site and tried reinstall as an Administrator user (from a completely new Eclipse), to no avail.

Have anyone else encountered the same problem ?
My environment: Windows 7 32bit, Eclipse Luna 32bit (version: for Java EE developers), Google plugin for Eclipse 4.4, JDK: tried both 1.7 and 1.8 32bit

Thanks in advance for any suggestion and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have eclipse starting in older java. I had the same issue, my eclipse was running with Java 6. As soon as I started eclipse with JDK7 it starts showing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I can't believe I made such a mistake. The problem is that the Java version in the PATH of windows is jdk6 ! I tried both jdk7 and jdk8 in the preferences of Eclipse but what's important here is the jdk in the PATH (what actually starts Eclipse).