# No Google icon after installing Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse, google-cloud-tools

In order to install the **Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin 1.3.0**, I followed instructions provided by Google on https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart .
The plugin is listed as installed in the Eclipse Marketplace, but the Google icon doesn't appear on the toolbar.

My environment is Windows 10 64 bits, Eclipse Oxigen (Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Release 4.7.0), JDK 1.8.0_131 64 bits, Python 3.5.1 64 bits.

My environment variables are:
[click here to see the environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUYmG.png).

I read a similar question on Stack Overflow ([no-google-icon-after-installing-the-google-plugin-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717126/no-google-icon-after-installing-the-google-plugin-eclipse)) but I'm not sure that answers are appropriate to my case.

Has anyone encountered the same problem?
Could you tell me how to get that Google icon on my Eclipse toolbar so that I can create a Google App Engine Standard Java Project in order to deploy it online?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
I :

- launched Eclipse as an administrator;
- uninstalled Google Cloud Tools;
- restarted now;
- exited Eclipse;
- re-launched Eclipse as an administrator;
- installed Google Cloud Tools;
- restarted now.

The icon appeared on the toolbar.